# How do I slide pictures from right to left on a slideshow in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I don't know anything about Javascript.
I am using this code for a slideshow, and I want to slide pictures from right to left.

Below is my code:

```
$(function() {
    $('.slides img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function() {
        $('.sliders :first-child')
            .fadeOut(2000)
            .next('img')
            .fadeIn(2000)
            .end()
            .appendTo('.sliders');
    }, 10000);
});
```